# Use of argparse subparser works in command line but fails test with AttributeError

Tags: python, argparse

I have

```
def list(self):

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()
    parser_list = subparsers.add_parser("list")
    parser_list.add_argument('query', type=str, nargs='?')
    args = parser.parse_args()

...

    if args.query:
...
```

In command line the above works well and I can do both of the commands below.

```
python file.py list
python file.py list query
```

I have some tests set up that attempt to use just list (and no query). The tests complain that:

```
if args.query:
   ^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'Namespace' object has no attribute 'query'
```

As an example, here is one of the tests.

```
def test_basic(self):
    """Test that list command prints correct string."""
    with patch("todo.open", mock_open(read_data="One\nTwo\n")):
        Handler().list()
    expected = dedent(
        """\
        1 One
        2 Two
        ---
        2 item(s)
        """
    )
    self.assertPrinted(expected)
```

Comment: When debugging, include a `print(args)` to get a better idea of what the parser has seen.  `python file.py` will run, but `args` namespace won't have a `query` attribute.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I have done this printing and seen this. However, I am still unsure as to how to handle it. I have just changed the if to:

if hasattr(args, 'query') and args.query is not None: ...

Which works but it looks a bit clumsy, don't you think?

Comment: Actually, I think a better question for me to ask is why the command line sets the query attribute to None when omitted by the user, but the test framework sets no attribute at all when omitted by the user.

Comment: `query` is added to the Namespace by the `parser_list`.  If that parser isn't run, `query` will not appear, not even with the default value.  Normally you'd have several subparsers, each of which will create their own set of arguments.

Comment: Often you'd do something like `parser.add_subparsers(dest='cmd'`), and then check `args.cmd` to see if it's 'list' before trying to use `args.query`.  In both production and testing, 'query' is conditional on the use of the 'list' parser.  You use subparsers because you want to use different sets of arguments for each of the 'tasks'.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense, thank you. All of the tests that are failing are the ones that do not mock command line arguments. The ones that do, pass.

Comment: Sorry just re-read this and I think I am still confused. I believe that when I execute my program from the command line, query is None in the args namespace. In testing, those tests that do not mock the command line args, fail as the namespace does not have query in the args namespace at all. Could you just explain this slightly different behaviour between testing and production?

Comment: In the test case, are you passing `list` as an argument?  By default the subparsers argument is not required, so calling `python file.py` is ok, and `query` will be missing.

Comment: Sometimes no args are passed at all in tests, I think. The test that I have included in my above post just calls the method directly, no args. I did not write the tests and I did not want to add the args in because I thought the person who wrote them was trying to isolate little parts of the functions and test them, as people often seem to do in testing.

Comment: I would like to solve this problem in the test though because as it stands, I have code in my list function that is simply there to make these types of tests pass. I was thinking that having code that is only relevant to your tests, and never needed in production, is bad practice. It is also a bit confusing to someone reading the code.